# How is the $\pi$ bond of carbon in graphene possible?

Tags: graphene

[This](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2012/501686/) paper states that the carbon atoms in a sheet of graphene form 3 $\sigma$ bonds with the neighbouring carbons and a $\pi$ bond that comes out of the plane (in the $z$ direction).

Unfortunately the paper doesn't go into detail about what this $\pi$ bond is exactly. I thought it could be a lone pair but carbon can't do that with 3 $\sigma$ bonds already in place.

What is the bond bonding the carbon to? How is this $\pi$ bond possible?

Comment: There's an extra electron left from each carbon that it shares with the carbon below it. Btw, the configuration is not very stable and thus graphene layers can slide.

Comment: Graphene is like a sheet of aromatic rings (aromatic as in the benzene molecule).

Comment: @YuzurihaInori So if it only shares with one other carbon, does that mean that there has to be an even number of carbons?

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question as I now understand how the $\pi$ bond forms.

As @YuzurihaInori said;

> There's an extra electron left from each carbon that is shares with the carbon below it.

This image is what helped my understanding of it 
[image: pi bonds]

The $\pi$ orbitals form together to make the "$\pi$-bands" the [paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2012/501686/) was talking about. It also helped me to understand why graphene is such a good conductor: due to delocalised electrons in the $\pi$ orbitals.